# Hide form behind PayPal payment

Tags: 7, webforms, payment-gateways

The site I'm working on at the moment has a competition that requires the following workflow:

1. User creates an account
2. User pays fee with PayPal (ideally a button)
3. User enters multi step/page form

I'm at a loss as how to best implement this:

The **Webform Paypal** module allows me to include a button but when I put it on the first page of my form it doesn't redirect me back to continuing the rest of the submission after payment.

The **Payment for Webform** module has too many steps:

1. First you have to click 'add payment' which opens a new window
2. Then you have to select a quantity
3. Then you have to select a payment method
4. Then you're taken off site

The **Webform Paymethod Select** module has the same issue as the first module except I get a 404 after completing a payment.

I'm wondering if payment should be part of the form at all? Is it possible to hide the webform until a successful payment has been received? I guess I'd have to write something custom for that.

Comment: I believe paypal allows you to specify a "redirect URL" which specifies where the user should be sent after payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a separate page with a generated PayPal button. You can include a hidden field called 'custom' that you can use to pass in your own data so I included the current user's UID. After a successful payment you can get PayPal to send a POST with the details to a URL of your choosing. I set up a custom page with a listener then updated the user account specified by the UID.